# why does VNC `d`-key seem to minimize the Terminal of the Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, tightvnc

Why is it that when I am using a VNC viewer to access a VNC server, the 'd'-key seems to minimize the Terminal in the server's ubuntu desktop?  By `Terminal` I mean the console-like window.

So for example, if I want to issue the `ls` command, no problem.  If I want to issue the `pwd` command, the last letter, `d`, causes a minimize.

I am using TightVNC 1.3.9 on both ends and Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server go to `System/Preferences/KeyboardShortcuts`.

Disable the entry called `Hide all normal windows and set focus to the desktop`.  The backspace key disables it.

Reboot the server and restart the VNC server.